# On a LENS printer, does the head move, or is it table that moves when printing?

Tags: z-axis, metal-printing, printing-powder

I'm wanting to know how a LENS printer moves to create 3D prints.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst this is not a definitive answer, if you watch the video on their website, [LENS 450 Systems](https://www.optomec.com/3d-printed-metals/lens-printers/low-cost-metal-3d-printer/), it is the bed that moves in the X and Y axes - the head remains static. The bed also *appears* to move in the Z axis, after each layer (as there is noticeable bed wobble).

However, the head is on an armature so it could be that which moves - it is not entirely clear.

[LENS 450 System for 3D Printed Metals](https://www.optomec.com/3d-printed-metals/lens-printers/low-cost-metal-3d-printer/?wvideo=0vb8ql6iv9)

Note that the MR-7 system appears to be similar to the 450, with its "3 Axis CNC Control System". However, the 850-R differs, inasmuch that it has:

- 5 Axis CNC Control System
- XYZ gantry + tilt-rotate table

which are not mentioned in the specifications of the 450 and MR-7, so the 850-R could well differ from the video.